# docker phpmyadmin Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose

I get error in http://localhost:8080/index.php
user bralion pass 123

```
 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
mysqli_real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Try again
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Try again
```

here is my docker_compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: bralion-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      networks:
        itbcode_net:
          ipv4_address: 10.3.0.11
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./itbcode_docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8089:80"

    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      container_name: bralion-mysql
      working_dir: /application
      networks:
        itbcode_net:
          ipv4_address: 10.3.0.12
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=bralion
        - MYSQL_USER=bralion
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      ports:
        - "8088:3306"

    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      links:
        - mysql
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        PMA_PORT: 3306
      ports:
        - '8080:80'


    php-fpm:
      build: itbcode_docker/php-fpm
      container_name: bralion-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      networks:
        itbcode_net:
          ipv4_address: 10.3.0.13
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ~/.ssh/:/root/.ssh/
        - ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history
        - ./itbcode_docker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini

    redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: sd-redis
```

UPDATE 1

i Update config (add ~/.composer and add phpmyadmin to itb_network)

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: bralion-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      networks:
        itbcode_net:
          ipv4_address: 10.3.0.11
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./itbcode_docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8089:80"

    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      container_name: bralion-mysql
      working_dir: /application
      networks:
        itbcode_net:
          ipv4_address: 10.3.0.12
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=bralion
        - MYSQL_USER=bralion
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      ports:
        - "8088:3306"

    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      networks:
          itbcode_net:
      links:
        - mysql
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        PMA_PORT: 3306
      ports:
        - '8080:80'


    php-fpm:
      build: itbcode_docker/php-fpm
      container_name: bralion-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      networks:
        itbcode_net:
          ipv4_address: 10.3.0.13
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ~/.ssh/:/root/.ssh/
        - ~/.composer/:/root/.composer/
        - ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history
        - ./itbcode_docker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini

    redis:
      image: redis:alpine
      container_name: sd-redis
      networks:
          itbcode_net:

    elastic-search:
      image: willdurand/elk
      networks:
          itbcode_net:
      container_name: bralion-elastic
      ports:
          - 81:80
      volumes:
          - ./elk/logstash:/etc/logstash
          - ./elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns

#    node:
#      build:
#        context: ./itbcode_docker/node
#      working_dir: /srv
#      volumes:
#        - ./:/srv/



networks:
  itbcode_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.3.0.0/16
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: i add error  ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the two containers are in different networks. The `phpmyadmin` container is only in the `default` network (because you didn't specify another network for it), the `mysql` container is only in the `itbcode_net` network (once you specify another network, the container will be removed from the `default` network unless you also add `- default`). You need to either add `phpmyadmin` to `itbcode_net` or add `mysql` to `default`, otherwise they can't communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1):

`webserver`, `mysql`, and `php-fpm` are on the network `itbcode_net`.

`phpmyadmin` and `redis` are not so `phpmyadmin` cannot find that address.

Comment: What is best practice ? I want just statc ip for webserver, other containers dont need public ports , ip - do i need create network ?

Comment: Outside scope of StackOverflow but having the IPs does not make it publically assessable. The ports declaration makes it visible on the host.